# Installing SSIS, SSAS and SSRS on a separate Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssrs, ssas

Please is there any benefit from installing SSIS, SSAS and SSRS on a separate server from the SQL Engine instance?

Apart from additional license implications, are there any other considerations for the decision?

I'd appreciate links to any useful research articles on this please.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any benefit from installing SSIS, SSAS and SSRS on a separate server from the SQL Engine instance?

Easier to tune performance since instances do not fight for CPU, memory or IO.

More secured - individual with windows admin permissions can only affect one server not all of them

Easier to get reboot approval.

Comment: thank you very much, these are very helpful points. Are you able to point me in the direction of any helpful articles on the subject please? Thanks again for your time and the helpful answers

Comment: The article about multiple SQL instance stacking but still applicable. https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/12/install-multiple-instances-sql-server/

Comment: Very much appreciated @Sergey, yes the article is applicable and helpful. Thanks again for all your time.